# Conclusion from all negative premises

Tags: logic

the following image shows a logic puzzle from a German website:
https://www.einstellungstest-fragen.de/wp-content/uploads/C_LG_schlssflgrn_6.png

The text on the image translates word-for-word to:

> No animals are tired.
> Some animals are not hungry.
> Therefore are some animals not tired.

The test website marks the conclusion as wrong, with the explanation that no sensible conclusion is possible when all premises are negative.

I don't understand this reasoning here. In my mind,

- the first premise is equal to *all animals are not tired*
- the second premise doesn't tell us much that is useful. At least, it implies that some animals exist do exist.

So if all animals are not tired, and some animals exist, then there exist some animals which are not tired.

Is the conclusion is correct? Why (not)?

Comment: You are right. See [Fallacy of exclusive premises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_exclusive_premises): the fallacious conclusion when in a categorical syllogism we have both of its premises negative is that relating the terms "tired" and "hungry".

Comment: I don't fully understand your reply @MauroALLEGRANZA. 
Could you rephrase it?
Thank you!